# Vim new window for program execution, similar to cwindow

Tags: vim, execution

I am using Vim to edit/compile individual `cpp` files (`makepgr=g++\ -g\ %`) and want to execute the resulting binaries ideally using a shortkey like <kbd>F6</kbd>. The desired behavior is then, to open a new window similar to `:cwindow` with a fixed maximal height (say 20 lines), which contains the program output. I also want to be able to close this window again with another shortkey like <kbd>F7</kbd>.

As a bonus, it would be great to have the execution time of the program shown in the windows title/status.

EDIT: the binaries I am talking about are non-interactive! They mostly read some input files, do data manipulation, write their results to other files and have some output while doing so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This little script should do the trick:

```
let s:title="ProgramOutput"

function! Open_output_window()
    let winnr = bufwinnr(s:title)
    if winnr != -1
        exe winnr . 'wincmd w'
        return
    endif

    let bufnr = bufnr(s:title)
    if(bufnr == -1)
        let wcmd = s:title
    else
        let wcmd = '+buffer' . bufnr
    endif

    exe 'silent! botright vertical 80 split ' .wcmd

    silent! setlocal buftype=nofile
    silent! setlocal noswapfile
    silent! setlocal nobuflisted
endfunction

function! Close_output_window()
    let winnr = bufwinnr(s:title)
    if winnr != -1
        exe winnr . 'wincmd w'
        close
    endif
endfunction

nmap <F6> <ESC>:call Open_output_window()<CR>:r ! %:r.exe<CR>
nmap <F5> <ESC>:call Close_output_window()<CR>
```

Most of this code came from the taglist.vim plugin - it's reasonably simple to understand.
You can modify the `split` command for your window size preferences.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! One tiny things though: how can i flush the buffer/window before execution of the binary (so that hitting F6 multiple times gives only one output)

Comment: Changing the nmap to `nmap <F6> <ESC>:call Open_output_window()<CR>ggdG:r ! %:r.exe<CR>` would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is helpful in any way, since you're asking about vim:

My first thought about how to solve this problem would be usage of GNU screen. Reason is not, that vim isn't capable of doing this, but that vim isn't exactly usable as terminal emulator, so running some interactive programs doesn't work. Plus screen is relatively easy to configure.

I would of course write a specialized screen config for that task.

Comment: Surely this is a possibility that works. However switching between vim and some other program/console - even in screen - is what I hoped to avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Add to the vimrc:

```
 map <F6> :tabnew<CR>:.!ls -la<CR>
```

Open vim and press <kbd>F6</kbd>. You should see in the new tab with the output of the command `ls -la`. Now, if this works for you then you can change it (replace myprog with the name of your executable):

```
 map <F6> :tabnew<CR>:.!./myprog<CR>
```

You can even give name to this tab:

```
 map <F6> :tabnew myprog<CR>:.!./myprog<CR>
```

Do not like tabs? Replace `tabnew` with `split` or `vsplit` wich allows to split window horizontally or vertically. Want splitted window to be small? Use

```
 map <F6> :5split myprog<CR>:.!./myprog<CR>
```

Replace `5` with any other number you likes. Also add

```
 map <F7> :tabclose<CR>
```

to get ability to close the tab by pressing <kbd>F7</kbd>.

P.S. You can replace hard-coded `myprog` name with `expand("%:r").".exe"` (for Windows) or just `expand("%:r")` (for *nix) as already been said.

Comment: This is a good start. When I run F6 according to you description it will always open a new window rather than refresh the old one. Can this be fixed? Also: what would be the F7 alternative for the 'split' case?

Answer (score 0):

You could redirect the input into the quickfix window (similar to how `:make` works):
`:cex system(expand("%:r").".exe")`

You can navigate through quickfix history using `:colder` and `:cnewer`

I realise this isn't exactly what you were looking for, but hopefully it's near enough to be useful.

Comment: Is it possible to have similar to the quickfix window other "named" windows which I can redirect output to?